# core plot in iPad applications

Tags: ipad, core-plot

In core plot I saw plot symbol,how can I fill plot symbol with color? Can please explain with an example?
And also can make one plot symbol in a specified (x,y) position?
From where I got the complete tutorial for core plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plot symbols are an optional part of the scatter plot. There are lots of examples throughout the example apps included with Core Plot, including a demo in the Plot Gallery that shows all of the predefined plot symbol shapes.

You can have the scatter plot show the same symbol at every data point by setting the `plotSymbol` property. If you want different symbols at different points, implement one of the following datasource methods:

```
-(CPTPlotSymbol *)symbolForScatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot
                           recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
-(NSArray *)symbolsForScatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot
                 recordIndexRange:(NSRange)indexRange;
```

Each plot symbol has a `fill` and `lineStyle` that determine the inside fill and the border line style. These are standard `CPTFill` and `CPTLineStyle` objects used throughout Core Plot.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer.Thank you so much